# Change color of part of object inside mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, modifiers

I have a complex bezier curve in blender using the Cycles engine that loops in and out of different mesh objects.
The curve has a simple diffuse material and the mesh would normally be invisible (or completely transparent). What I would look is for the parts of the curve that are inside a mesh to be a different color (say white outside, red inside) and preferably even for this to be a different color for different meshes. Notably I would like the parts of the curve that are behind the mesh (from the perspective of the camera) to be the normal. I understand that somethings like this can be achieved with a complex setup of boolean modifiers but I was hoping there was a more flexible way to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a sketch or a mock-up? There seems to be a lot of requirements there.